# eddy current direction

Tags: current, electromagnetism

As far as i understand eddy current direction is determined by lenz's law.
But the following example -
[image]
describes the currents and magnetic field direction when the current in the coil increases -
[image]
but when the current decreases -
[image]
the magnetic field also decreases, so according to lenz's law the eddy currents are directed so they induce a magnetic field in the same direction as the magnetic field of the coil - which is counter clockwise (unlike the clockwise eddy currents in the image).
how can that be?? eddy currents are supposed to stay in the same direction!

Comment: What is your source for eddy currents staying in the same direction?  They will alternate as the magnetic field that induces them changes direction.

Comment: yeah, what i meant - when the current I > 0 and increases (the second image), the magnetic field increases, thus the eddy currents will be in the direction as in the first image. But when the current I>0 and decreases! (as in the third image), the magnetic field decreases, therefore i thought that the eddy currents should change their direction (opposite to the red in the first image). But many books, you included, said that it keeps in the same direction. why?

Comment: As @vir states, the eddy current will alternate.  It will always oppose the direction of the magnetic field in the primary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eddy currents do not stay in the same direction, nor do they always oppose the direction of the magnetic field in the primary. A good way to understand them is as follows: *The eddy currents will create a magnetic field which opposes the **change** in the magnetic field of the primary.*

Sometimes this will be in the opposite direction as the primary magnetic field, such as in the first diagram you drew of a sine wave, and other times this field will be in the same direction as the field of the primary, such as the second diagram you drew.

In the first diagram, the magnetic field of the of the primary is getting stronger. Therefore, to oppose this change, the eddy currents will create a field in the opposite direction as that of the primary.

In the second diagram, the magnetic field of the primary is getting weaker, and so to oppose this change, the eddy currents will create a magnetic field that 'tries' to strengthen the magnetic field of the primary. It is therefore in the same direction as the magnetic field of the primary.

The eddy currents in these two cases are going in opposite directions relative to one another.